# Who has priority to close a question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I asked a questions on a small Stack Exchange community. I got a few answers, one of them noted that a similar question is answered already. This question wasn't exactly the same, but in essence it is the same and answers to that other question covered mine well enough. So I marked my question as a duplicate.

The top user of the community pointed that it is not a duplicate, and it's not me but the community who decide whether the question is a duplicate or not.

So who is right? Who has priority, me or community? I assumed that if I have enough instruments to do it technically, I have the right to do so. And funny enough, the user who closed it on my behalf is Community, the background process.

Comment: There's nothing stoping any user with the required privileges who disagrees with the closure to vote to re-open the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That Community closed your question is just a technicality. There is no other way to let you close your own question without the additional (4) close votes.

Now, who is right? In the end the community is. Your question is just a part of the global knowledge base. If a top user (with a lot of experience in the tag) tells you that the question is not a duplicate, he most certainly has the capability to undo the closing and reopen it.

That doesn't mean we have to make a war of it. In the end, closing the question prohibits it from receiving more answers. If that is the worst that can happen, just leave it open. If the link is in an answer, it is visible to others already. You might want to accept that answer in order to make the link more prominent, if it is really that important.